# How to add custom html tags to swal using content element

Tags: html, css, alert, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I want to make the text in the swal `bold` and with a custom `text color` and since `html:true` is no more supported, I tried to set a `<span>` and set my custom `style` to the html tag, but it is not working, and I searched for a solution but I got no answers.

**The Code**

```
swal({

    title: "Summary",
    content: '<span>"counter " + this.counterType_1 + ": "+ this.counter_1_from.value.counter_1 +" - Sold Liters: " + liter_sold_1</span>',

    className: "success",
    closeOnClickOutside: false,

    closeOnEsc: false,
    dangerMode: true,
    buttons: {
    submit: {
        text: "Submit",
        value: "submit",
    },
    noAction: {
        text:"Cancel",
        value: "Cancel",
    },
    },

})
```

**What I tried**

```
var _html= '<span>"counter " + this.counterType_1 + ": "+ this.counter_1_from.value.counter_1 +" - Sold Liters: " + liter_sold_1</span>',
content: _html,
```

but also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a way by using `createElement()` method which takes param an html tag,

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('h1');
wrapper.innerHTML = 'this is bold text';
swal({
    content:wrapper,
    title: "Summary",
    className: "success",
    closeOnClickOutside: false,
    closeOnEsc: false,
    dangerMode: true,
})
```